# Highlight range for ex command

Tags: highlight

I'm trying to add more ex commands to my vim repertoire and I was wondering if there is setting or plugin that would allow to highlight the lines addressed by the command, if a range is give e.g., if I type

```
:-5,-3m.
```

I would like some highlight on the lines -5 and -3 (either the line number or the whole line or something like that), while I'm typing the command, until I actually execute it. If only the begin or end or the whole block is highlighted is not so important me.

I searched the vim help and the web for some time but did not find anything useful so far.

Comment: This seems like it could be pretty non-trivial if not implemented in source code. You might get by with a `cnoremap` though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit complicated, I'll try to explain it in different abstraction levels.

### Level 0

our goal is simple:

- update command range highlight after entering command line
- update command range highlight while typing in command line
- clear command range highlight when leaving command line

### Level 1

We will use [:h CmdlineEnter](https://vimhelp.org/autocmd.txt.html#CmdlineEnter) , [:h CmdlineChanged](https://vimhelp.org/autocmd.txt.html#CmdlineChanged) , and [:h CmdlineLeave](https://vimhelp.org/autocmd.txt.html#CmdlineLeave) to implement our goals.

```
augroup cmdline_range_highlight
  au!
  autocmd CmdlineChanged : call s:update_cmdrange_highlight()
  autocmd CmdlineEnter : call s:update_cmdrange_highlight()
  autocmd CmdlineLeave : call s:clear_cmdrange_highlight()
augroup end
```

### Level 2

Let's implement functions mentioned in `Level 1`, their name should already tell you what they do.

```
" last command range and hightlight match id returned from matchadd()
let s:cmdrange = []
let s:cmdrange_hid = -1

function s:update_cmdrange_highlight() abort

  let cmdline = getcmdline()

  " skip  v_:
  if cmdline =~# '\V\^''<,''>'
    return
  endif

  " skip if range not changed
  let cmdrange = s:get_cmdrange(cmdline)
  if s:cmdrange == cmdrange
    return
  endif

  " update highlight area
  call s:clear_cmdrange_highlight()
  let s:cmdrange_hid = matchadd('VISUAL',
        \ printf('\v%%>%dl.*%%<%dl', cmdrange[0]-1, cmdrange[1]+1))
  let s:cmdrange = cmdrange
  redraw

endfunction

function s:clear_cmdrange_highlight() abort
  if s:cmdrange_hid != -1
    call matchdelete(s:cmdrange_hid)
  endif
  let s:cmdrange = []
  let s:cmdrange_hid = -1
endfunction
```

### Level 3

We need to implement `s:get_cmdrange` to get current cmd range

```
function s:get_cmdrange()
  ????????????
endfunction
```

There has no builtin function to get cmdrange without executing it(correct me if I'm wrong), the only way to get a cmdrange is executing a cmd. We can't execute current command, we must construct another labor command with current cmdrange text:

```
function s:get_cmdrange(cmdline) abort

  let range_text = matchstr(a:cmdline, s:cmdrange_pat)
  if empty(range_text)
    return []
  endif

  try
    let cpos = getcurpos()

    " silent is used to reverse reversed command range
    exec printf('silent %s call Tech_get_cmdrange()', range_text)
    return [s:tech_cmdrange_line1, s:tech_cmdrange_line2]
  finally
    call setpos('.', cpos)
  endtry
endfunction

function Tech_get_cmdrange() range
  let s:tech_cmdrange_line1 = a:firstline
  let s:tech_cmdrange_line2 = a:lastline
endfunction
```

Our labor command here is `silent original_command_range_text call Tech_get_cmdrange()` .

We use [:h :func-range](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#%3Afunc-range) to get cmdline range from `vim`.

### Level 4

The last step is to init `s:cmdrange_pat` , it's used in Level 3 to extract cmdline range from cmdline.

A [:h cmdline-ranges](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html#cmdline-ranges) is one [:h :range](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html#%3Arange) or two `:range` joined by `,` or `;`

A `:range` is some basic pattern followed by multiple optional `[+-][number]`.

```
function s:build_cmdrange_pattern()
  " a range is various pattern followed by multiple optional [+-][number]
  let range_atoms = [
        \ '\d+',
        \ '[.$%]',
        \ "'[0-9A-Z]",
        \ '\/.{-}\/',
        \ '\?.{-}\?',
        \ '\\\?',
        \ '\\\&',
        \ '\\\&',
        \ ''
        \ ]
  let range_basic = printf('%%(%s)', join(range_atoms, '|'))
  let range_optional = '%(\s*%([+-]\d*)*)'
  let range_pat = printf('\v%%(%s\s*%s*)', range_basic, range_optional)

  " cmdrange is two ranges joined by, or ;
  let cmdrange_pat = printf('\v\C^%s([,;]%s)?', range_pat, range_pat)
  return cmdrange_pat
endfunction
let s:cmdrange_pat = s:build_cmdrange_pattern()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, works but has some minor issues, e.g. if I misstype something in the range, I get a bunch of messages and have to leave the ex command and start again. But its a very good starting point which has all the bits and pieces I need.

Comment: One error is caused by add and delete multiple space in the beginning of command line, I have fixed it, and some other small issues. You may find the newest version here https://github.com/dedowsdi/.vim/blob/master/autoload/misc/hlcmd.vim

Answer (score 1):

Finding an "easy" way.

The idea is to drop to linewise Visual mode and then get back restoring the command-line contents.

```
" some regex magic to match a range pattern:
" . or $ or % or number or mark or /pat/ or ?pat? or \/ or \? or \&
" optionally followed by ++/--number
let s:pat = '([.$%]|\d+|''[[:alnum:]''\[\]]|/.*/|\?.*\?|\[/?&])?([+-]+\d*)?'
" full pattern is: lineno followed by , or ; and another lineno
" nearly every field is optional though
let s:fullpat = '\v^\s*' . s:pat . '([,;]' . s:pat . ')?'
function! s:getrange(line)
    return matchstr(a:line, s:fullpat)
endfunction

" use <l1>GV<l2>G to visually select range
" then restore the command line with feedkeys()
command! -range -nargs=1 ToVisual exe 'norm!' <line1> . 'GV' . <line2> . 'G' |
    \ redraw | call feedkeys(":\<C-U>" . <q-args>, 'n')

" Press <C-X> while in the command line to make a visual selection
" The command line contents will be restored automatically
cnoremap <silent><C-X> <C-\>e(getcmdtype() == ':' ?
    \ 'silent ' . <SID>getrange(getcmdline()) . 'ToVisual ' : '') .
    \ getcmdline()<CR><CR>
```

Comment: Hi Matt, thank you, I've tried it and it seems to work sometimes and sometimes not, for :s it starts higlighting once I press the / after s, for :m and :co it doesn't highlight anything. I therefore did go with the solution from @dedowsdi.